# Image rotation and translation in a report

Tags: qgis, rotate, translation

QGIS 3.22.4

I am working on an indication panel project, to connect different numbered points together (as junction nodes)

In summary: along a road, we have to install panels (on stakes for example)
Roads, junctions and stakes are in different shapefiles.
I have also a shapefile (line) that contains the panels that should be placed. Each panel is represented by a line, in the right position regarding the stake it is attached to.

Differents attributes are filled in for each panel, the attributes that are important for my question are the point number you are going to, and the direction of the arrow to show the way to follow (important if you have a crossing, for example)
The direction is defined by the angle the arrow should point to. Example, if you have to take the path on your right, this field has 90, if you have to go forward, 0; if you have to turn left, 270)

There is a report (defined as an atlas) that shows some map info (a global view of the path and a zoomed view of the stake and the panel)
On this report, I want to illustrate what the panel should look like (for the printer).

First challenge: when the general direction is forward or on the right, I have to put the Number (of the junction you want to go) on the left, and put the direction arrow on the right. I found a solution for that, by putting an expression in the X position with a formula like if direction > 180°, Pos1, Pos2  for the number, and if direction > 180°, Pos2, Pos1 for the arrow, and it works fine.

The problems appears when I want to rotate the arrow in line with the direction needed. I used the rotation parameter and put a formula in it using the direction value. The arrow (a JPEG image just containing the arrow) turns to the correct direction BUT the place of the arrow is also changing, and I do not understand why.

I worked with the point of reference (center, upper left,...) the behaviour is different and the movements are different, but always move.
I tried to understand the logic (but not sure I succeeded) and try to put a formula in the Y coordinate, but did not succeed and did not undestand which formula is applied first.

What should I do to combine rotation and translation of the arrow?

As illustration this is what I want to simulate on the report:

[image]

Comment: It could be useful to add what is _actually_ happening to the arrows, as well as what you want to achieve. It will help others to visualise the problem you are having.

Comment: What I want is shown on the image, and what I have is that the arrows moves "erratically", even out of the page, when moving along the different pannels. Supprisingly, when i move back along the pannels, it's still going away and not coming back to their original position